# Using rsync's archive flag without copying symbolic links

Tags: linux, rsync

As stated in `rsync`'s man page, the `-a` (archive) switch is equivalent to `-rlptgoD`. However, I have a situation where I don't want symbolic links retained. Is there any way to keep using the `-a` switch and prevent copying of symbolic links? I could write `-rptgoD` every time, but it's a bit long.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try the following:

> rsync -a **--no-links** ...

or, the slightly shorter:

> rsync -a **--no-l** ...

Note that the `--no-links`/`--no-l` switch must come **after** the `-a` switch on the command line, otherwise the `--links` implied by `-a` is turned back on again.

Comment: I don't see the --no-links option in the [rsync help pages](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html). When did they add this option?

Comment: @palswim: See the `--no-OPTION` option in the man page. `-l`/`--links` is implied by the `-a` option, and hence can be turned off by the corresponding `--no-OPTION` option.

Answer (score 5):

No. You could use an alias instead. Put the line

`alias mrsync="rsync -rptgoD"`

inside your ~/.profile and after the next login, you can call just `mrsync` and have these parameters implicit with the alias.